# Jagged Alliance 2 1.13 weapon "M" marking

Tags: jagged-alliance-2

This is question about Jagged Alliance 2 modded by [1.13 mod](http://ja2v113.pbworks.com/w/page/4218339/FrontPage)

What does mean Turquoise "M" besides weapon?
It appears and disappears in my inventories pretty often and i had no luck in finding any description..
It looks like its based on some particular condition based on mercenary activity..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your weapon is mounted on something it will get some of the bonuses that apply to prone stance. Check the description of "Weapon resting features" in Ja2_Options.ini.

[*(reponse from silversurfer on another forum)*](http://thepit.ja-galaxy-forum.com/index.php?t=msg&goto=346145)

Comment: Could you please include a link to the response on the other forum?